# Resonant and non-resonant tori density in non-degenerate system

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-systems, ergodicity

I'm following the discussion on the page 290 of *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* by V. I. Arnol'd (you can download it [here](https://loshijosdelagrange.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/v-arnold-mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-1989.pdf)), and I've encountered the fact that in a nondegenerate system, the resonant and nonresonant tori are dense - even if the former have Lebesgue measure zero and the latter are of full measure.

Such fact is asserted in various sources around the web, but I couldn't find a proof - in fact, could you help me in answering the two problems proposed by Arnol'd?

[image]